# Adding the same workitem to two different sprints in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How can I add the same work item to two different sprints/sprint boards?

My scenario is given below.

I have a big team that is following a longer sprint length (1-month sprint cadence for example)) and a sub-team that is trying 1-week sprints.  I have done the project and team configuration (using area paths and iterations pats etc.) such that the sub-team sees only their backlog view and the big team sees the whole backlog.  I can drag the work items from either one of the backlog for either one of the teams to corresponding  1-month sprint board (for the big team) or 1-week sprint board (for the sub-team).

My question is as follows:

The bigger team wants to see all the stories as part of the month-long sprint. In other words when they have standups they want to see the sub-team's 1-week sprint stories also in their sprint board for the month-long sprint.  I tried to add the same story into both month-long sprint for the big team and 1-week sprint for the sub-team. But Azure DevOps cannot keep the work item in both the sprints at the same time.  It you add it to month-long sprint board, it is removed from the 1-week sprint board.

How I can have the work item be added to both the sprints?  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can set up sub-teams and sub-sprints using Azure DevOps logic, then the work items will be automatically synchronized on the backlogs of both teams.

As shown below:

"Team 2" is a sub-team of "Case0103 Team". And "Week 1" sprint is a sub-sprint of "Iteration 1".

[image]    [image]

Then in Sprints, "Case0103 Team" can view work items of "Iteration 1".

[image]

"Team 2" can only view work items of "Week 1".
[image]

Here are the detailed steps:

1. Create a sub-team. You can click [Configure a hierarchy of teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/configure-hierarchical-teams?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) for detailed steps.
2. Create sub sprints. You need to go to Project Settings -> Boards/Project configuration, then choose your sprint and click "New child".

[image]

3. Set iteration paths. Go to Project Settings -> Boards/Team configuration -> Iterations. Select different teams by navigation bar at the top and select or remove sprints. Team members can only see sprints shown here.

[image]